# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of null

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, typescript, connection

I am trying to connect to my Postgres DB, just to see if I can connect, I have one entry in it. But whenever I try to connect I get connect null error, why is this so?

My Database model

```
    'use strict';

    import { Pool, Client } from 'pg';

    export default class Postgresql {

        private pool: Pool;

        constructor(private database: string, private host: string, private port: string, private user: string, private password: string) { };
        /* Create a PostgreSQL DB instance */
        connect = (): Promise<Pool> => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.pool = new Pool({
                database: this.database,
                host: this.host,
                port: Number(this.port),
                user: this.user,
                password: this.password
            });

            this.pool.connect().then(() => {
                resolve(this.pool);
            }).catch(err => reject(err));
        })

    }
```

My database service that is importing the model

```
    import Postgresql from "@root/src/app/models/database.model";

    const databaseService: {

        pool: Postgresql['pool'];
        init: () => Promise<string>;
        execute: (query: string, params: any, next?: any) => Promise<any>;
    } = {
        pool: null,
        init: () =>
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (!databaseService.pool) new Postgresql(process.env.DATABASE, process.env.DATABASEHOST,
                    process.env.DATABASEPORT, process.env.DATABASEUSER, process.env.DATABASESECRET)
                    .connect()
                    .then((pool: Postgresql['pool']) => databaseService.pool = pool)
                    .catch((err: Error) => reject(err));
                resolve();
            }),
        async execute(query, params, next?) {
            let client = await this.pool.connect();
            try {
                const result = await client.query(query, params);
                console.log(result);
                next(null, result);
            } catch (e) {
                next(e, null);
            } finally {
                client.release();
            }
        }
    }

    export default databaseService;
```

calling the db from server.js

```
        databaseService.init();
        let query = "SELECT * FROM ?";
        let params = "postgres"
        databaseService.execute(query, params);
```

and my env var, ive double checked that they were correct but ill post anyway. this is my first time trying to connect to a db using env var, and doing it through a service, so if I am doing something wrong, please let me know

```
    DATABASE=postgres
    DATABASEHOST=localhost
    DATABASEPORT=5432
    DATABASEUSER=postgres
    DATABASESECRET=password
```

```
    (node:11020) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ENGU3002\Documents\Template\src\app\services\database.service.ts:20:38)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\ENGU3002\Documents\Template\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:110:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\ENGU3002\Documents\Template\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:106:16)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\ENGU3002\Documents\Template\src\app\services\database.service.ts:16:24)
    at C:\Users\ENGU3002\Documents\Template\src\app\server.ts:20:25
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\ENGU3002\Documents\Template\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:110:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
(node:11020) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11020) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What's the exact message and what line is reporting the error? From a quick glance I can't see this.pool being initialised anywhere in the databaseService.

Comment: Edited the post to show error code, and I put databaseService.init(); in the server.js to create the instance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your databaseService.init() is async but you aren't waiting on it so the call to databaseService.execute is happening before the promise returned by init() resolves.

You either need to call

```
await databaseService.init()
```

or

```
databaseService.init().then(....)
```

and do the query inside the then.

Not directly related to this but if you declare a function as async any returned value will automatically get wrapped up in a promise so you don't need to explicitly declare promises which makes the code easier to read and easier to spot issues like this. eg the init method could look something like:

```
init: async () => {
    if (!databaseService.pool) {
        databaseService.pool = await new Postgresql(
            process.env.DATABASE,
            process.env.DATABASEHOST,
            process.env.DATABASEPORT,
            process.env.DATABASEUSER,
            process.env.DATABASESECRET
        ).connect()
    }
```

Comment: Both of those calls still give me an error on the same line, and I did change the way my init method to the way you have mentioned. I am still getting used to using await but this has helped me understand it a bit more, thank you. The init method is a little different looking though, the async is in a different place. The error message is still the same though